# MVC Partial View - Link to location on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Let's say I have an Html page with divs.
If I want to link to a specific location on that page, I can create a url like http://www.example.com**#mylocation**

Now let say I'm calling that page as a partial view instead.  Can I still get to those page locations?
@Html.Partial("_MyPartialView")

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still get to those page locations.

Rendering a partial doesn't do anything special; the final HTML is the same as if you pasted the partial's contents into the same place. (You can even access `ViewBag` and it should have the same variables in it from the controller.)

If you view the final page source, you'll still see your HTML anchors. You can manually append `#mylocation` in your browser URL and see that it still works.

Comment: OK,  but what does the razor syntax look like if I want to add that extra part on?

Comment: There's nothing razor-specific to that. You just add the `id` to the div (eg. `mylocation`), and specify a link that points to `#mylocation`. Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my question.  If I want to go to a page location on another page, I could just put this in an anchor tag http://www.example.com#mylocation.
But, if I wanted to display that second page embedded in my first page, I don't use an anchor tag, I use a Partial View call @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView").  This, however just returns the the whole second page and is not directed to find a specific location.  I wanted to see if I could do the equivalent to the first method, but with a partial view (go to a specific location in the partial view.)

Comment: There's nothing special to Razor about this. You just add the location anchor tag on the second page, include it as a partial on the first page, and you should be able to go to it with the first page's URL plus the `#whatever` attachment.